# Excel - count a specific value based on a part of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I thought this would be a no brainer. But I really need help to solve it.

I have a row of dates: 10 july 2020, 11 july 2020 and so on (Swedish excel).
Below each date are strings for example "FP". I wish to achieve a counter for each "FP" that is below a specific month of a year, such as july 2020.

The way I approached this was with

```
=COUNTIFS(G1:UG1;"*july 2020";G2:UG2;"FP")
```

However the * doesn't do what I want it to. Is there another way to do this?

Please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates are true dates and as such the `july 2020` is just a format of a number and not actually there.

Instead BookEnd the date:

```
=COUNTIFS(G1:UG1;">="&DATE(2020;7;1);G1:UG1;"<"&DATE(2020;8;1);G2:UG2;"FP")
```

Comment: Makes total sense! This worked perfectly, thank you so much! :)